# How to stop immediately a task which is started using an ExecutorService?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I have tried many different ways to immediately stop a task which is started using an ExecutorService, with no luck.

```
Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>(
    public Void call () {
        ... do many other things here..
        if(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
            return null;
        }
        ... do many other things here..
        if(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
            return null;
        }
    }
));

if(flag) { // may be true and directly cancel the task
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

Sometimes I need to cancel the task immediately after it is started, you may be curious why I want to do this, well you may imagine a senario that a user accidentally hits the "Download" button to start a "Download Task" and he immediately wants to cancel the action because it was just an accidental click.

The problem is that after calling **future.cancel(true)**, the task is not stopped and **Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()** still returns **false** and I have no way to know the task was stopped from inside the call() method.

I am thinking of setting a flag like *cancelled=true* after calling future.cancel(true) and checking that flag constantly in the call() method, I think this is a hack and the code could be very ugly because the user can start many tasks at the same moment.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving what I want?

**EDIT:**

This really drives me mad. I have spent almost a day on this problem now. I will try to explain a little bit more for the problem I am facing.

I do the following to start 5 tasks, each task will start 5 threads to download a file. and then I stop all 5 tasks **immediately**. For all of the method calls below, i start a thread(ExecutorService.submit(task)) to make it asynchronous as you can tell from the suffixes of the methods.

```
int t1 = startTaskAysnc(task1);
int t2 = startTaskAysnc(task2);
int t3 = startTaskAysnc(task3);
int t4 = startTaskAysnc(task4);
int t5 = startTaskAysnc(task5);

int stopTaskAysnc(t1);
int stopTaskAysnc(t2);
int stopTaskAysnc(t3);
int stopTaskAysnc(t4);
int stopTaskAysnc(t5);
```

in **startTaskAysnc()**, I simply initiate a socket connection to remote server to get the size of the file(and this certainly is gonna take some time), after successfully getting the fileSize, I will start 5 threads to download different parts of the file. like the following(the code is simplified to make it more easy to follow):

```
public void startTaskAsync(DownloadTask task) { 
    Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>(
        public Void call () {
            // this is a synchronous call
            int fileSize = getFileSize();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted());
            ....
            Future<Void> futures = new Future<Void>[5];
            for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; ++i) {
                futures[i] = executorService.submit(new Callable<Void>(){...});
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; ++i) {
                futures[i].get(); // wait for it to complete
            }            
        }
    ));
    synchronized (mTaskMap) {
        mTaskMap.put(task.getId(), future);
    }
}

public void stopTaskAysnc(int taskId) {
    executorService.execute(new Runnable(){
        Future<Void> future = mTaskMap.get(taskId);
        future.cancel(true);
    });
}
```

I noticed a weird behavior that after I called stopTaskAsync() for all 5 tasks, there would always be at least one task that got **stopped**(i.e. Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted() return true), and the other 4 tasks kept running.

And I have tried your suggestions by setting an UncaughtExceptionHandler, but nothing comes out from that.

**EDIT:**

The problem was solved in this link: [Can't stop a task which is started using ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636908/cant-stop-a-task-which-is-started-using-executorservice)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) of `Future.cancel(boolean)` says that:

> If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning
>   parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be
>   interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.

so it's quite certain that the thread that executes the task *is* interrupted. What could have happened is that one of the

> ... do many other things here..

is accidentally clearing the `Thread`'s `interrupted` status without performing the desired 
handling. If you'll put a breakpoint in `Thread.interrupt()` you might catch the criminal.

Another option I can think of is that the task terminates before capturing the interrupt, either because it's completed or thrown some uncaught exception. Call `Future.get()` to determine that. Anyway, as asdasd mentioned, it is a good practice to set an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Comment: Hi, @yair, I have edited my question, please give me some help if you have a clue. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is very dangerous: you're using a thread pool to execute tasks (which I'll call downloaders), and the same thread pool to execute tasks which

- wait for the downloaders to finish (which I'll call controllers)
- or ask the controllers to stop

This means that if the core number of threads is reached after the controller has started, the downloaders will be put in the queue of the thread pool, and the controller thread will never finish. Similarly, if the core number of threads is reached when you execute the cancelling task, this cancelling task will be put in the queue, and won't execute until some other task is finished.

You should probably use a thread pool for downloaders, another one for controllers, and the current thread to cancel the controllers.

Comment: Hi, JB Nizet. You are right, I was aware of that before posting the question here, but the problem I am facing does not seem to have anything to do with the strategy of using thread pool, because I ensured the minimum number of threads is enough for running all controllers and downloaders for 5 tasks. Anyway I will take your suggestion and use 2 separate thread pools to run controllers and downloaders and cancel controllers in the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109288/java-thread-weird-thread-interrupted-and-future-canceltrue-behaviour). The main point is that cancel method raises InterruptedException. Please check if your thread is still running after cancellation? Are you sure that you didn't try to interrupt finished thread? Are you sure that your thread didn't fail with any other Exception? Try to set up UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Comment: Hi, @asdasd, I have edited my question, please give me some help if you have a clue. Thanks you.