# Can't stop a task which is started using ExecutorService

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

Sorry I have to open a new thread to describe this problem.

This morning I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632773/how-to-stop-immediately-a-task-which-is-started-using-an-executorservice), there're some replies but my problem is still not solved.

This time I will attach some runnable code(simplified but with the same problem) for you to reproduce the problem:

```
public class ThreadPoolTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Future<Void> futures[] = new Future[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; ++i)
            futures[i] = startTask(taskExecutor);

        for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; ++i)
            System.out.println("futures[i].cancel(true): " + futures[i].cancel(true));

        System.out.println("Cancel DONE.");
        taskExecutor.shutdown();
    }

    private static Future<Void> startTask(final ExecutorService taskExecutor) {
        Future<Void> f = taskExecutor.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
            public Void call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    downloadFile(new URI("http://stackoverflow.com"));
                    while(true) {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": " + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                        if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            } 
        });
        return f;
    }

    private static void downloadFile (final URI uri) throws Exception {
//        if(true) return;
        Socket socket = new Socket (uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() == -1 ? 80 : uri.getPort());
        return;
    }
}
```

The code above will most likely be trapped in an infinite loop(you may want to run the code multiple times to witness what I saw), as you can see in the main method I have called **futures[i].cancel(true)** for all tasks, I don't know why this is happening, this has been torturing me for more than a day.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is probably related to the fact that many IO methods (networking or disk) cannot deal with interrupts.  You might want to comment out the socket line in downloadFile and see what happens.  Also, it's not clear what you mean by "trapped in an infinite loop": it keeps printing out the thread numbers or it jams?

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the socket line, it works as expected and the tasks are properly canceled. by "trapped in an infinite loop" I mean it keeps printing out the thread names, which means Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() returns false all the way. Now you have pointed out the fact that IO methods can't deal with interrupts(which I didn't know about), is there a way to intercept the interrupt from within the call() method and then cancel the task? now the socket line seems to swallow my interrupt exception.

Comment: I googled a bit and it seems that the behavior of Socket is undefined for interruption and that some different JVM have different behaviors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've played with your code, and noticed that the thread's interrupt status is sometimes true before the socket creation, and false after.

I have tried interrupting a thread and calling the Socket constructor, and the thread always stays interrupted after. I also tried removing the shutdown of the threadpool, and the problem continued to happen.

Then I have tried using 5 different URIs, rather than always the same one. And the problem never happened.

So I wrote this simple program, showing that the thread pool is not the culprit, but the socket is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final URI uri = new URI("http://stackoverflow.com");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket (uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() == -1 ? 80 : uri.getPort());
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());
            }
        };
        new Thread(r).start();
    }
}
```

And indeed, when 5 threads create a socket to the same host and port, 4 of them have their interrupt status cleared.

Then I tried to synchronize the socket creation (on a single lock, but I guess you might use one lock per host/port) :

```
synchronized(lock) {
    try {
        Socket socket = new Socket (uri.getHost(), uri.getPort() == -1 ? 80 : uri.getPort());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and TADA... the problem disappeared. I would open a bug at Oracle to signal the problem.

Comment: Thank you! JB Nizet, you've saved me. Good to discover that it is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and it didn't stop, as you said.

Didn't have much time to investigate why it behaves so, but I found out that declaring the executor service's threads as daemons made the problem go away :

```
private static ExecutorService TaskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5, new ThreadFactory() {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    }
});
```

I'll come back if I find a better explanation.

Comment: Setting a thread as daemon makes it unable to outlive the main thread, if you do more things or simply block there in the main thread after canceling all the tasks, you may notice the problem still exists.

Comment: Yes, making process "deamon" is simply hiding the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that task are not started when you try to cancel them. I added `Thread.sleep(100)` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; ++i)
      futures[i] = startTask(taskExecutor);
Thread.sleep(100);
for (int i = 0; i < futures.length; ++i)
     System.out.println("futures[i].cancel(true): " + futures[i].cancel(true));
```

and everything was cancelled ok.

Comment: Nope, try several times and you'll see it still hangs

Comment: As the JavaDoc for Future<T>.cancel() says: "Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. `If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run`. If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task." A task can be canceled even if it is not started.

Comment: @OlivierCroisier Hm, maybe my machine performace is higher. I tried it with 15 ms and it still works, but hangs with 10ms pause. Try 500ms

Comment: @Neevek Yeah, Doc is Doc, but look closer at JVM sources. It's based on nonblocking API, atomics, etc. So between .submit() and .cancel() in current code task is somewhere beteen READY and RUNNING (and it's not synchronized). So I think it's possible that task really started to execute AFTER it was cancelled because jvm code is not synchronized.

Comment: @Neevek For example, I put `f.cancel(true)` at the end of the `startTask` method, everything was ok and tasks haven't even start (I suppose task executor've read task status (CANCELLED) and haven't started to execute it).

Comment: I didn't look into the JVM sources. but as JB Nizet pointed out, it is a bug, the `interrupted` state gets cleared if different sockets are initiated to connect to the same URI, and somehow the thread will never be interrupted.