# Thread.isInterrupted always returns false

Tags: java, linux, multithreading

Maybe, it is a duplicate question of [Thread.isInterrupted doesn't work, Thread.interrupted does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2012259/1122665).
But since I use a quite different way to call `Thread.isInterrupted()` and have upgraded to a newer jdk, I just think this may be caused another kind of problem.

There are three threads (not including the main thread) in my program.

- a `sleep` thread sleeps for 10 seconds;
- a `checker` thread checks if the `sleep` is interrupted by another thread;
- an `interrupter` interrupts the `sleep` thread as long as it's started.

And here is my program:

```
package foobar;

public class Foobar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Thread sleep = new Thread(new Sleep());
        sleep.start();

        Thread checker = new Thread(new InterruptedChecker(sleep));
        checker.start();

        Thread interrupter = new Thread(new Interrupter(sleep));
        interrupter.start();
    }
}

class InterruptedChecker implements Runnable {

    private final Thread thread;

    InterruptedChecker(Thread thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (thread.isInterrupted()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The thread is interrupted.");
    }
}

class Sleep implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

class Interrupter implements Runnable {

    private final Thread thread;

    Interrupter(Thread thread) {
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("interrupting...");
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

The interesting thing is that somethings (quite a lot) the program keeps running and doesn't print the message `"The thread is interrupted."` which means that the `sleep.isInterrupted()` returns `false`, but **somethings it does**.

Here is the `java -version` of my pc (Ubuntu 13.10 64bit):

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

After I read [Thread.isInterrupted doesn't work, Thread.interrupted does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2012259/1122665) above, I tried to compile my code in a different machine using an older jdk and it worked.

And, here is the `java -version` of the machine (Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 3) 64bit):

```
java version "1.6.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_06-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0-b22, mixed mode)
```

**So my question is that:**

1. Is there something wrong in my program?
2. If it doesn't, does the multicore cpu or the 64 bit system have something to do with this problem?

### EDIT

Thanks for Peter's comment.

> What problem are you trying to solve?

I just read [the post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html?ca=drs-) as I have stated in my comment, where in the Chapter of **"Don't swallow interrupts"** it says that,

> code higher up on the call stack can learn of the interruption and respond to it
>   if it wants to.

So I'm not sure if the `checker` thread in my program acts as, what it is called here, *code higher up*. I just have a try to prove the post is right. But it seems that there is something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interrupted flag is reset as soon as it is triggered. i.e. once sleep() have been interrupted, the flag is reset to false.

---

EDIT

> So I'm not sure if the checker thread in my program acts as, what it is called here, code higher up. I just have a try to prove the post is right. But it seems that there is something wrong.

IMHO there is nothing higher up about another thread.  What you generally have in mind is something like this.

```
public static void main(String... ignored) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<?> future = es.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            methodA();
        }
    });
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    future.cancel(true); // interrupts task.
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (CancellationException expected) {
        // ignored
    }
    es.shutdown();
    es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Time to cancel/shutdown was %.1f milli-seconds%n",
            time / 1e6);
}

private static void methodA() { // doesn't throw any checked exception
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        methodB();
}

private static void methodB() {
    boolean conditionWhichIsTrue = true;
    if (conditionWhichIsTrue)
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
}
```

prints

```
Time to cancel/shutdown was 1.7 milli-seconds
```

however, if you swallow the interrupt by commenting out the `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` line this takes about 50 seconds to stop because you only interrupted one call to sleep.

Comment: [Thread.isInterrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted()) is not static. Only your second paragraph applies here: the status is cleared as soon as `sleep` is interrupted.

Comment: If I doesn't misunderstand [this post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html?ca=drs-), I think `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` restores the interrupted status of `true` after it is interrupted and won't be reset.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so why it works on another machine. Strange, isn't it?

Comment: It depends on the thread scheduling and the state of the JIT/Optimizations whether you can notice the interrupted state for a short time or not. Keep in mind that this lag shall be as short as possible so it’s rather a sign of a *better* jdk if it is so short that you can’t notice it anymore.

Comment: @rAy You are trying to see a very short lived event in a way which has no guarantees of success or failure.  This is bound to have strange behaviour.  You might find that running on a different box, a different JVM or even after you have started more programs on your computer gives different results. e.g. some machines run slower for  programs which are loaded higher in memory or in a different NUMA region.

Comment: @rAy You might find the behaviour changes if you haven't run the test for as long e.g. try a milli-second or less, or with a debugger or profiler enabled.

Comment: @Holger Is there any pattern I can follow to achieve the some function of the program above, monitoring another thread and doing something as soon as the monitored thread is interrupted?

Comment: @rAy There is no guarentee that the interrupted thread will see that it is interrupted if it doesn't check.  You appear to be trying to solve a problem in a way which is only bound to be unreliable.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Why can't the interrupted thread takes an action when it is interrupted?  Can you take an action when the thread is finished instead?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've edited my question which contains the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @rAy I have added an example of why it matters.  Higher up means higher up the stack, not in an unrelated thread.

Answer (score 0):

This question also bothered me for some time. After some investigation I got the answer.

When `InterruptedChecker` checks `isInterrupted` state, the `Sleep` thread already died. Try to add some time consuming code after `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in `Sleep` class and try again.

**'interrupted' status of a thread is cleared when that thread dies.**