# Why does thread.isInterrupted() return false even after I call Thread.currentThread().interrupt()

Tags: java, multithreading

When I run this test, why does `sleepThread.isInterrupted()` always return false?

(I had to execute `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` to set the interrupted flag when catch a `InterruptedException`).

```
@Test
public void t() {
    Thread sleepThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("have been interruptted....");
                e.printStackTrace();

                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                // in here this.isInterrupted() will return true
                System.out.println("now , instant interrupt flag : " 
                + this.isInterrupted());
            }
        }
    };
    sleepThread.start();

    try {
        sleepThread.interrupt();
        Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);

        // in here ,why sleepThread.isInterrupted() return false ?
        System.out.println("sleep thread interrupt flag : " 
        + sleepThread.isInterrupted());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
have been interruptted
now , instant interrupt flag : true
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
   at com.roundwith.concurrent.Interrupt_Test$1.run(Interrupt_Test.java:15)
sleep thread interrupt flag : false
```

Comment: here is a similar question didn't resolve : [Thread.isInterrupted always returns false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677604/thread-isinterrupted-always-returns-false)

Comment: Sidebar: This looks like an ill-advised way to use interrupts. What kind of behavior are you after, and why do you need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because by the time the last statement is reached

```
System.out.println("sleep thread interrupt flag : " + sleepThread.isInterrupted());
```

the thread would be dead.

Try to remove the 2-second sleep in the main thread and you would see the difference (try several runs -- it may still print false but at least the main thread has a chance to see the other thread alive).

Comment: You *may* see the difference. There is still no guarantee that the "main" thread here will have time to see the sleep thread before it dies.

Answer (score 0):

try to change,

```
Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
```

to

```
//Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
```